# Wondering if a document has been supplanted on a website

Tags: windows

I see a file on a website that is now named with % signs in place of the underscore in the original file name.  Could this mean that the original file was replaced with another file?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely been 'escaped' That is, translated into a system that will not break across different computers. An underscore would be replaced by %5F 
There's a reference here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: While not specifically said - when the URL is decoded, that %5F will be turned back into an underscore. *They are identical in the end*.